# AS3 move object back to first frame from current position in tween

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, if-statement

I have an object with an instance name of arrow that moves across the page on a motion tweet when a button is pressed. When the button is released I want the arrow to move back to the start of the tween frame by frame.

I have set up an if statement when the button is released and its current frame is more than 1 to go back 1 frame.

So far the arrow is ignoring the if and stopping due to the else statement.

```
btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, out);

function out(e:MouseEvent){

if(arrow.currentFrame > 1){
arrow.gotoAndStop(arrow.currentFrame - 1);
}else{
    stop();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You would probably be better off making another tween on the timeline that goes backwards then just playing that.  Another option is to use a third party tweening library like tweenlite since in there you can easily setup animations to run forward or in reverse.

Are you sure arrow is the name of the movie clip that you want to run the frames backwards on, or is that the instance of the element that changes over some other movie-clips timeline?